# Windows form distance measuring program acts up after multiple images opened up

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have a program which allows the user  to open an image and measure it by dragging the mouse over it. The image opens up in a picture box when you press a button. The program works after two images are opened, but not after three images are opened. After the third image, the measurements are grossly overestimated. 
Here is the part of my code which opens the image:

```
private void openPlan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// open plan folder
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = null;

        // open file dialog   
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\complete Lumber Estimation Tool\Plans\";
        // image filters  
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            trackBar1.Value = 4;
            zoom = 1.0F;
            imgOriginal = null;
            // display image in picture box  
            imgOriginal = new Bitmap(open.FileName);

            pictureBox1.Image = imgOriginal;
       }
  }
```

Is this mainly a problem with how a windows form program stores data?
If so, how do I make sure the program isn't using any data or parameters from the previous image?

Comment: BTW: Always dispose images,
specially with open file handles. Use: imgOriginal?.Dispose(); - pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose(); instead of = null

Comment: That actually fixed my issue, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As in my comment:**
Always `dispose` images, specially with open file handles.
Use:

```
imgOriginal?.Dispose();  
pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
```

instead of: `.Image = null`

**...in a greater detail:**
The `Image` class is using `GDI`, which causes to open handles. These handles are not closed automatically by just loosing the reference in your application. They are not collected by the [garbrage collector (learn.microsoft.com Garbrage-Collection)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/).

This can result in unpredictable behavior of your application or beyond.
e.g: If you load an image from a file, the open handle results in a **filelock**(!) also if you just wand to display the image.
For that cases, you can load the whole image into a intermediate `System.IO.MemoryStream` object.
Encapsulate the image from the original source like this:

```
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath));
var Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

This will load the file into the memory and the image out of it.
Take care to **Dispose the stream and the Image** after your use or when loading a different image.

Comment: I thought i fixed the issue with your tip yesterday, but i checked it again today, and there still appears to be same issue after i open the third picture. What else can i do to remove image data?

Comment: @EricLopez-Reyes Is the third image always the same? You have to provide the code where and how you measure - opening isnt really the problem now i think

Comment: The program works fine for any picture until the third picture is opened. I also added the measuring code

Comment: I made a rookie mistake in one of my zoom methods. I meant to save a particular variable as 200. This value was to be divided by a scale factor (to deal with different sized pictures). When the pictures were the same size, the new value was 200/ scale factor/ scale factor instead of just 200/ scale factor.

Comment: expected something like this - good to hear you have found a solution